Eigenfunctions of the laplacian are analytic on a manifold
I am currently trying to understand why the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian are analytic.
The context is the following, I consider a Riemannian manifold $M$ with metric $g$, this structure naturally defines the operator $\Delta$ which is the Laplacian. What I can see is that on a compact set $\Delta$ is an elliptic differential operator thus using a standard result I obtain that eigenfunctions of $\Delta$ are smooth. However I am not sure to know how to deduce that these functions must be analytic.
For the usual case $M = \mathbb{R}^n$ I have seen this post: Why are Dirichlet eigenfunctions real-analytic?. However in my more general case the Laplacian does not have such a simple expression.
In a few words from what I understand is that in the case $M = \mathbb{R}^n$ we are able to bound the weak derivatives (which are also the real derivatives) and prove that the Taylor expansion converges, thus the function is analytic.
To have an explicit non trivial example I am working with a space that is similar to upper half plane $\mathcal{H}$ which consists of complex numbers such that $Im(z) > 0$ and it's metric is $g(z)(u, v) = \frac{(u, v)}{Im(z)^2}$. In this case the Laplacian is $\Delta = y^2 \left( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 x} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 y} \right)$ and it's volume form is $w(z) = \frac{1}{Im(z)^2} dx \wedge dy$.
Any help is greatly appreciated!
Edit: As pointed out in the comments, I also assume that the manifold and it's metric is analytic.

What does it even mean for a function to be analytic on a smooth manifold? A priori that depends on a choice of charts, right? So it seems the manifold itself needs to have a real analytic structure, and then we should also require that the metric be analytic. That's certainly true in your case but I want to point out that this is extra structure on top of being a Riemannian manifold.

Yes of course I forgot to mention this but we must require the analytic properties you mentioned.
